# child div goes out of parent div

Tags: html, parent

does anybody know why my child div class goes out of its parent div class? I don't know what's wrong with it!

Link to Fiddle and code attached!

Thanks for your help!

https://jsfiddle.net/cqynLsqu/

ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

```css
.table { display: table; }
.row { display: table-row; }
.cell { display: table-cell; }
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px #000 solid; width: 100%;">
 <div style="background-color: #012055; background-image: url(../images/tableTitle.png); height: 40px; line-height: 40px; color: #fff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;">
  0
 </div>

 <div style="width: 100%; margin: 5px;">
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 </div>

 <div class="table" style="width: 100%; margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px; border: 1px #000 solid;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="cell" style="background-color: #012055; background-image: url(../images/tableTitle.png); height: 40px; line-height: 40px; color: #fff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;">
    0
   </div>  
   <div class="cell" style="background-color: #012055; background-image: url(../images/tableTitle.png); height: 40px; line-height: 40px; color: #fff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;">
    0
   </div>
   <div class="cell" style="background-color: #012055; background-image: url(../images/tableTitle.png); height: 40px; line-height: 40px; color: #fff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;">
    0
   </div>
   <div class="cell" style="background-color: #012055; background-image: url(../images/tableTitle.png); height: 40px; line-height: 40px; color: #fff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;">
    0
   </div>
   <div class="cell" style="background-color: #012055; background-image: url(../images/tableTitle.png); height: 40px; line-height: 40px; color: #fff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;">
    0
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
   <div class="cell">
    0
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
    0
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
    0
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
    <b>0</b>
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
    <a href="0">0</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </div> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
<div class="table" style="width: 100%; margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px; border: 1px #000 solid;">
```

to this:

```
<div class="table" style="width: 100%; margin-right: 5px; border: 1px #000 solid;">
```

The `margin-left` is pushing the content out.

Comment: And if you put all your CSS in the same place (into the stylesheet or document's `<head>`) you'd have probably worked out what was going wrong yourself.

Comment: is there no way to keep margin to have a space between my table and parents border?